# Firestore function cloud messaging not working properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

What I am trying to do is run a job when at specific time it will fetch a specific field from my document and send a notification to the user using the fetched contents.

But the problem is notification body remains empty. I tried to log if whatever I am fetching from the documents are empty or not. But as per the logs the logs the quote variable is not empty.

Please point me what I am missing

```
exports.sendDailyQuotes = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 7 * * *').timeZone('Asia/Kolkata').onRun(async (context) => {

    var today = new Date();

    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

    var currMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;

    var dateQry = today.getDate() + "-" + currMonth;

    var quote;

    admin.firestore().collection('quotes').doc(dateQry).get().then(snapper => {
        quote = snapper.data().english;
        return "";
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    });

    var dailyQuote = {
        notification : {
            title : "Daily Quote",
            body : quote,  //This is staying empty
        },
        topic : 'notifications'
    }

    let response = await admin.messaging().send(dailyQuote);
    console.log(response);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using promises correctly on the call to Firestore.  Calling `then` doesn't pause the code like `await` does.  Your code will simply immediately move on to the call to FCM before waiting for the query to finish.

You should instead use await again to pause your code to wait for the result of `get()`.

```
    const snapper = await admin.firestore().collection('quotes').doc(dateQry).get()
    quote = snapper.data().english;
```

If you want to catch error on a call the returns a promise, you should use try/catch around the use of `await`.

I strongly suggest taking time to learn how to use promises effectively, or you will keep running into strange errors like this when implementing Cloud Functions code.

Comment: Thanks I am actually trying to learn but sometimes youtube videos and even the documentations are not understandable so I hope you understand

Comment: I'm going to be frank here - YouTube tutorials for Firebase products are not a great way to learn programming languages.  The tutorials typically assume you already know the language.  I suggest making an effort to learn JavaScript first, by itself, before trying something complicated in Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks again for guidance